# How do I address "Error in attr(test, "text")(fit, sim) : attempt to apply non-function" when a running mixed effect model power analysis with simR?

Tags: r, power-analysis

I'm trying to run a power analysis with an archival dataset using the simR package.I found a helpful guide here: https://pablobernabeu.github.io/2023/ggplotting-power-curves-from-simr-package/. When I initially ran everything about 2 weeks about, it worker and I got the expected output. Now, when I run it, I get the error "Error in attr(test, "text")(fit, sim) : attempt to apply non-function". I'm not sure why it is no longer working. I don't believe I changed anything that would affect it, but it's possible that I accidentally deleted something or loaded a package that conflicts with the ones running the power analysis. Can anyone help solve this issue (and let me know if I've made any other mistakes in running the power analysis)?

```
library(simr)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(utils)
library(dplyr)

# Plot power curve. This function plots the output from simr::powerCurve()
# or from combine_powercurve_chunks()

powercurvePlot = function( powercurve, 
                           
                           # Format interactions
                           interaction_symbol_x = TRUE,
                           
                           # Value(s) to which the X axis should be expanded
                           x_axis_expand = NULL,
                           
                           # Approximate number of X-axis levels
                           number_x_axis_levels = NULL ) {
  
  # Load required packages
  require(dplyr)    # data wrangling
  require(stringr)    # text processing
  require(simr)     # used for summary()
  require(ggplot2)  # plotting
  require(ggtext)   # enable more formats and HTML code in plot title (&times;)
  require(Cairo)    # plot format
  
  plot =
    data.frame(summary(powercurve)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = nlevels, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, label = nlevels)) +
    geom_ribbon(fill = 'grey94') + geom_errorbar(colour = 'grey40') + geom_point() + 
    # Print sample size by each point
    # geom_label(colour = 'grey30', fill = 'white', alpha = .5, 
    #            nudge_x = 5, nudge_y = -0.03, label.size = NA) +
    # Draw 80% threshold
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, color = 'gray70', lty = 2) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = 'Power', limits = c(0, 1), 
                       breaks = c(0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1),
                       labels = c('0%', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%')) +
    scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = number_x_axis_levels) + 
    expand_limits(x = x_axis_expand) + labs(x = 'Number of participants') + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, margin = margin(t = 8)), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, margin = margin(r = 7)), 
          axis.text = element_text(size = 9), 
          axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'grey50'),
          plot.title = element_textbox_simple(size = 10, width = unit(1, 'npc'), 
                                              halign = 0.5, lineheight = 1.6, 
                                              padding = margin(5, 5, 5, 5),
                                              margin = margin(0, 0, 1, 0),
                                              r = grid::unit(8, 'pt'), 
                                              linetype = 1, fill = 'grey98',
                                              box.colour = 'grey80'),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black'),
          panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank())
  
  
Plot title, conditional on replacement of colons in the names 
of interactions.

# (1) If interaction_symbol_x = TRUE
if(interaction_symbol_x) {
    plot = plot + 
      # Display name of predictor alone in title instead of default label from 'simr'
      ggtitle(powercurve$text %>%
                str_remove("Power for predictor ") %>% 
                # Remove single quotation marks at the beginning and at the end
                str_remove_all("^'|'$") %>% 
                # Replace interaction colons with times symbols
                str_replace(':', ' &times; '))
    
    # (2) If interaction_symbol_x = FALSE
  } else {
    plot = plot + 
      # Display name of predictor alone in title instead of default label from 'simr'
      ggtitle(powercurve$text %>%
                str_remove("Power for predictor ") %>% 
                # Remove single quotation marks at the beginning and at the end
                str_remove_all("^'|'$"))
  }
  
  plot
  
}
```

```
fm <-lmer(dv_weighted ~ pre.no_event + post + (1|group), REML = T, data = data1)


#change slope (1/2 of observed)
fixef(fm)["pre.no_event"] <- 1.6


fm_extended_soc = extend(fm, along = 'soccode', n = 1000)

fit_powercurve_pre = 
  powerCurve(fm, fixed("pre.no_event"), 
             along = "soccode", breaks = c(20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 150, 200, 250,300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000), 
nsim = 10, progress = TRUE)

power_pre <- powercurvePlot(fit_powercurve_pre, number_x_axis_levels = 12) +
  xlab("Number of participants") +
  theme(plot.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 17))

power_pre`
```

Comment: use options(error=recover) to help debug